# Multiple Realm Collections in kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin, realm

I'm creating an Ecommerce App, and i want it's db to be collections of separate articles ,

```
class Articles : RealmObject { // Main Class
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.invoke()
    var title: String = ""
    var price: Int = 0
```

I want my db to be collections (Files) of : Clothes , Parfums , Accessories.. Each collection has the same fields as Articles above

I tried creating Multiple Dublicated Classes : class Clothes , class Parfums
...etc But that doesn't seems practicle

Answer (score 0):

Collections are not files - they are groups of related objects. That being said, technically they could be separate (Realm) files but that’s probably not what you’re after, or needed.

One option to consider simply adding a “type” property to your Article class - noting that “Articles” is plural and Realm objects are singular objects so better to name them accordingly.

```
class Article: RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.invoke()
    var title: String = ""
    var price: Int = 0
    var type: String = "" //the object type; Clothing, Parfume, Accessory etc
}
```

That allows you to look at all of the Article Objects as a group, or by filtering on the type property, view and work with them as a sub group (collection)

Realm objects can also be subclassed if the subclasses need different functionality than the parent class. For example a Parfume object would not need a clothing type (pant, shirt etc) so here would be a ClothingClass subclass or Article that has all of the attributes and properties of the parent class but also specific properties that only apply to Clothing

```
class ClothingClass: Article {
  var clothing_type: String //pant, shirt etc
}
```

Keeping in mind that none of this requires separate “files” unless you have a specific use case to implement separate Realm files.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply , but in my case I strictly need a separate realm files for a unique fetching Articles algorithms ,
Is there a way ?! Using enum classes or something ..

Comment: By files I means those classes defined in schema !

Comment: If this is going to be a sync'd ecommerce app, Realm actually handles those in separate 'files' anyway. However, with modern sync'd Realm there isn't really a need to create discreet files. Can you update your *question* with the additional details of why you need discreet files and what kind of algorithm requires that? I will update the answer with details once that is more clear.

Comment: I ask a detailed question about my problem , I hope u can help ^^ ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76872815/realm-dynamic-schemas-in-kotlin