# Realm dynamic schemas in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, realm

I sadly spent much time with this but no success , we have a B2B Ecommerce app that allows users to sell their products , we want to store that data by categories in separates schemas, Each category has a different properties :

```
class PhoneModel : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.invoke()
    var brand: String? = null
    var os: String? = null
}
```

and .. u get the idea !!

```
class ParfumModel: RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.invoke()
    var volume: Int? = null
    var taste: String? = null
}
```

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRealm(): Realm {
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder(
            // Set Of Object Models Using RealmDB !!
            schema = setOf(PhoneModel::class,ParfumModel::class,ShoeModel::class,))
            .build()
        return Realm.open(configuration = config)
    }
```

the purpose is : the user chose the item category than fill it's product info , is there a way to do that !
something like :

```
      val productcategory = when (userCategoryChoice) {
            Category.phone -> PhoneModel()
            category.parfum -> ParfumModel()
      }
```

then ..

```
productUseCases.addProduct(productcategory .apply {
// fill the data base, u get the idea 
}
```

i tries working with generic classes , Enums ... but no success

Comment: Yes, there are many ways you can do something like this. So many in fact, that this question is too broad to answer. Your `when` example is a good start, though. I recommend you expand on that a bit, then if you get stuck, ask a new question specifically about that.

Comment: Any codes will be much appreciated Jorn ! I don't think the problem is that simple as u describ, for me at least :/

Comment: We're obviously not understanding the actual issue because the question and goal is not clear; You've got two Realm models in the question, what's wrong with just using those models as is? What is the purpose of a third *Category* model? Why do you need separate schemas? Making them separate will negate being able to query across your data so that's generally not going to work. Won't subclasses work per by [prior answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76841040/multiple-realm-collections-in-kotlin/76842621?noredirect=1#comment135528473_76842621). Can you clarify?

Comment: Those models (Categories) are so different , so what's the point of fetching all of them (Their products) together then query each category items ?! , it would be more practical to fetch each category separately (no query is even needed then) !

Comment: I just discovered inheritance isn't supported either !! https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/schemas/define-realm-object-model/#inheritance

Comment: What a pain in my head !

Comment: I don't know what them above comment means. The categories are different. Yes, that's why there would be discreet models; PhoneModel and ParfumModel for example; they are different models because they contain different data. That's why I asked what the purpose of Categories is as that's not needed. And... inheritance is limited in React, not Realm - but there's nothing in your question that would indicate a need for inheritance anyway. Please review [Composition vs Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328163/is-inheritance-in-react-components-an-anti-pattern)